# In season 1 episode 7 "Justice" of Star Trek TNG didn't they violate the prime directive by introducing themselves to a non-warp society?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

The entire episode is about Wesley accidently walking on the Edo's grass, violating their laws in the process, and incurring the death penalty. Picard is concerned about violating the prime directive because he feels that if he doesn't abide by Edo law he is interfering in the affairs of another species.

However, isn't part of the prime directive that they don't make first contact with non-warp capable species? I thought that contact of that nature was considered detrimental to the natural development of non-warp species. We see an example of this in the Edo's view of god, the Enterprise sharing space with god, etc. So why is Picard so concerned about violating the prime directive in regards to saving Wesley when it appears that visiting a planet of a non-warp capable species for the sole purpose of shore leave and no attempt to conceal their identities or capabilities is a violation in the first place.

Comment: It sort of attempts to answer the question. I searched looking for a duplicate question. Maybe there should be a policy that states a standard format for how to refer to an episode that should be included in the question header. For ex s1 ep2 "title". Even though his question was similar once reading the description under the heading, the answers were pretty broad with only a couple sentences referring to this episode & it was lacking at best. We all know the PD is violated many times. It just seems odd that in this case it was in an ep that focused solely on the issue of the violating the PD.